# Custom Dimension with "Hit" Scope passing empty value for other hits

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a HTML single page application (it is a single HTML file, where i show page navigation as hiding and showing multiple div elements, so page navigations are not actual page loads, just switching divs)

I have created some 5 custom dimensions of "Session" scope, so they will be always present and tracked with some value.

However, I need a 6th dimension which will be populated only upon doing a particular operation such as clicking a button. So i have created 6th dimension and set its scope as "Hit". In the HTML application, as soon as the user clicks the button, i set the value for that dimension and do a send for that request (it is actually an 'ec' tracking), i can see that the 6th dimension value is also set.

The problem is, After this tracking, if i track any other event tracking or page view tracking, the same value is being passed for the cd6 parameter.

Could you please let me know if i am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. If you use ga("set".... for setting the dimension value it will be sent with each susequent interaction. If you send the dimension within the configuration object of your tracking call you should be fine. Can you post a code example for your tracking code (or even an url)  so that we can see what's going on ?

Comment: yes, i am internally using ga("set") first and then doing a ga("ec:send")
when you say sending dimension within configuration object, do you mean  to send this along with the ga("ec:send")?

NOTE - the application is single page html, and during HTML load, i set the GA id and other custom dimenstions. Problem is with just the dimension 6. Also, i have custom methods written, which will internally trigger actual "ga" methods, so not sure if sharing the code will help

Comment: As you said the other dimensions are session scoped, so they apply to each hit in any case. But if you use "set" the hit level dimension will be attached to every hit that follows the set call. I am not sure something like "ec:send" does exist, do you mean "ecommerce:send" (i.e. are you usind enhanced or standard ecommerce tracking) ?

Comment: yes, we are using enhanced ecomerce and i am sorry for misleading. it is just "send" and not ec:send. Is there a way to stop the "hit" level dimension from getting attached to every GA hit? That is my problem now.

Comment: Since that seems indeed to be your problem I've made an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a custom dimension via set it will apply to all hits that follow:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'mydata');
```

will attach the dimension to all following tracking calls (especially bad on a single page app).

You can pass a JSON object as second parameter to the ga("send") call instead and set the dimension there:

```
ga('send', {
  'dimension1': 'mydata',
});
```

That way the dimension is only sent with that pageview, later interactions will not be affected.

Comment: Thank you Eike :) , will try this out and update the thread with outcome, but tomorrow morning my time. Sorry for the delay